# Broken texture in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xamarin.ios, core-graphics, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using OpenTK in MonoTouch to render some textures in iOS, and some of the textures come up broken. This is a closeup of an iPad screenshot showing one correctly rendered texture (the top one) and two broken ones below:

[image: broken texture]

I'm not doing anything weird. I'm loading the texture from a semitransparent PNG using `CGImage`->`CGBitmapContext`->`GL.TexImage2D`. I'm rendering each sprite with two triangles, and my fragment shader just reads the texel from the sampler with `texture2D()` and multiplies it by a `uniform vec4` to color the texture.

The files themselves seem to be okay, and the Android port of the same application using Mono for Android, and the exact same binary resources renders them perfectly. As you can see, other transparent textures work fine.

If it helps, pretty much every texture is broken when I run the program in the simulator. Also this problem persists even if I rebuild the program.

Any ideas on how to figure out what is causing this problem?

Here's my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 spritePosition;
attribute vec2 textureCoords;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 color;

varying vec4 colorVarying;
varying vec2 textureVarying;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * spritePosition;
    textureVarying = textureCoords;

    colorVarying = color;
}
```

Here's my fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;
varying lowp vec2 textureVarying;
uniform sampler2D spriteTexture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(spriteTexture, textureVarying) * colorVarying;
}
```

I'm loading the image like this:

```
using (var bitmap = UIImage.FromFile(resourcePath).CGImage)
{
    IntPtr pixels = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height * 4);
    using (var context = new CGBitmapContext(pixels, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, 8, bitmap.Width * 4, bitmap.ColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast))
    {
        context.DrawImage(new RectangleF(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), bitmap);
        int[] textureNames = new int[1];
        GL.GenTextures(1, textureNames);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureNames[0]);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)All.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)All.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)All.ClampToEdge);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)All.ClampToEdge);
        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, 0, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, pixels);
        CurrentResources.Add(resourceID, new ResourceData(resourcePath, resourceType, 0, new TextureEntry(textureNames[0], bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)));
    }
}
```

and in my onRenderFrame, I have this:

```
GL.ClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
GL.UseProgram(RenderingProgram);
GL.VertexAttribPointer((int)ShaderAttributes.SpritePosition, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, squareVertices);
GL.VertexAttribPointer((int)ShaderAttributes.TextureCoords, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, squareTextureCoords);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray((int)ShaderAttributes.SpritePosition);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray((int)ShaderAttributes.TextureCoords);
//...
GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureEntry.TextureID);
GL.Uniform1(Uniforms[(int)ShaderUniforms.Texture], 0);
// ...    
GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.TriangleStrip, 0, 4);
```

That triangle strip is made out of two triangles that make up the texture, with the vertex and texture coordinates set to where I want to show my sprite. `projectionMatrix` is a simple ortographic projection matrix.

As you can see, I'm not trying to do anything fancy here. This is all pretty standard code, and it works for some textures, so I think that in general the code is okay. I'm also doing pretty much the same thing in Mono for Android, and it works pretty well without any texture corruption.

Corrupted colors like that smell like uninitialized variables somewhere, and seeing it happen only on the transparent part leads me to believe that I'm having uninitialized alpha values somewhere. However, `GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit)` should clear my alpha values, and even so, the background texture has an alpha value of 1, and with the current `BlendFunc`, should set the alpha for those pixels to 1. Afterwards, the transparent textures have alpha values ranging from 0 to 1, so they should blend properly. I see no uninitialized variables anywhere.

...or... this is all the fault of `CGBitmapContext`. Maybe by doing `DrawImage`, I'm not blitting the source image, but drawing it with blending instead, and the garbage data comes from when I did `AllocGlobal`. This doesn't explain why it consistently happens with just these two textures though... (I'm tagging this as core-graphics so maybe one of the quartz people can help)

Let me know if you want to see some more code.

Comment: Seeing some code might help people tell you if/where things can wrong.

Comment: @poupou I think I explained what and how I'm doing it, which I believe is more useful than just copy-pasting a long listing of code, but sure, I can post some code.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on the right track with the `CGBitmapContext`. It's not cleared by default. You need to make sure you fill it with transparent black before drawing your sprite to it, I believe.

Comment: It makes complete sense, and the function is called `DrawImage`, not `CopyImage`. I'll try it tonight when I get back home. However, this doesn't explain why it only happens with these two textures, and why it works fine with a few other semitransparent textures I'm using.

Comment: Just hypothesizing. Maybe I'm getting garbage just with these two images because they're small, and therefore I'm requesting a small amount of memory, which may be getting recycled from somewhere else; while for the larger textures, I may be getting fresh new memory blocks that the allocator clears. In the simulator most textures look bad because it's running with an entirely different allocator. Unfortunately, `Marhsal` doesn't seem to have a memset. I'll first try with `CGBitmapContext.ClearRect()`, and if that doesn't work, I'll interop memset or manually do it the `unsafe` way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it is just as I had expected. The memory I get with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` is not initialized to anything, and `CGBitmapContext.DrawImage` just renders the image on top of whatever is in the context, which is garbage.

So the way to fix this is simply to insert a `context.ClearRect()` call before I call `context.DrawImage()`.

I don't know why it worked fine with other (larger) textures, but maybe it is because in those cases, I'm requesting a large block of memory, so the iOS (or mono) memory manager gets a new zeroed block, while for the smaller textures, I'm reusing memory previously freed, which has not been zeroed.

It would be nice if your memory was allocated to something like `0xBAADF00D` when using the debug heap, like `LocalAlloc` does in the Windows API.

Two other somewhat related things to remember:

1. In the code I posted, I'm not releasing the memory requested with `AllocHGlobal`. This is a bug. `GL.TexImage2D` copies the texture to VRAM, so it is safe to free it right there.
2. `context.DrawImage` is drawing the image into a new context (instead of reading the raw pixels from the image), and Core Graphics *only* works with premultiplied alpha (which I find idiotic). So the loaded texture will always be loaded with premultiplied alpha if I do it in this way. This means that I must also change the alpha blending function to `GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.One, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha)`, and make sure that all crossfading code works over the entire RGBA, and not just the alpha value.

Comment: Depending on how you interpret `0xbaadf00d`, it could be nearly transparent, which would make the problem hard to spot for all but the most eagle-eyed users. Initializing to `0xff0000ff` would be better: Either opaque red or opaque blue, and impossible to miss either way.

Comment: That being said, [Xcode does have an option to turn on scribbling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Art/scheme_diagnostics.png), which uses `0xaa` (`0xaaAAaaAA`), which will be semi-transparent gray or white but otherwise work almost as well.